# mrjob error: DescribeJobFlows API is deprecated

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, mrjob

I am using mrjob for the first time and try to run the basic word count code on EMR. I followed every step in the document of mrjob [here](http://pythonhosted.org/mrjob/guides/quickstart.html) yet still got an error.

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://elasticmapreduce.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-03-31">   <Error>
    <Type>Sender</Type>
    <Code>ValidationError</Code>
    <Message>DescribeJobFlows API is deprecated. Please refer to http://docs.aws .amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/API/API_DescribeJobFlows.html for further in formation</Message>   </Error>   <RequestId>e300f5b0-3396-11e5-b377-5b3cd3427dd8</RequestId> </ErrorResponse>
```

What is the problem, how can I fix it?

The command line was as below

> python C:\Users\Administrator\MyIpython\word_count.py -r
>   emr C:\Users\Administrator\MyIpython\111.txt

I found someone having the same problem at mrjob google group [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mrjob/woQx-154i8U). Does it mean mrjob cannot function until a new release?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I believe the current version of mrjob is broken until the next release. The solution is already being worked on and planned for the next release.

An immediate solution is the list-clusters branch (which presumably will be merged with the master in the next release) : https://github.com/davidmarin/mrjob/tree/list-clusters

You will need to clone the mrjob repo from github, switch to the list-clusters branch, and install manually. The branch seems to solve the issue.

UPDATE:

For anyone looking at this issue now, looks like the branch has change:

> The list-cluster branch no longer exists; please use the v0.4.x branch
>   instead:
>   https://github.com/Yelp/mrjob/tree/v0.4.x

From the mailing list